# Iterate through ListView and get EditText-Field values

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I've created a ListView (myList) with one EditText-Field in each row (R.id.mannschaften). Under the ListView, I've created a Button and set an OnClickListener for it in the OnCreate()-Method.
Now when the Button is clicked, I want to iterate through the ListView and get the value of the EditText-Field in every row and save them in a String-List. But how do I do that?

Here is my Code:

```
private void ButtonClick() {
    /** get all values of the EditText-Fields */
    View v;
    ArrayList<String> mannschaftsnamen = new ArrayList<String>();
    EditText et;

    for (int i = 0; i < myList.getCount(); i++) {
        v = myList.getChildAt(i);
        et = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.mannschaften);
        mannschaftsnamen.add(et.getText().toString());
    }
    .....
}
```

I already know, that getChildAt is only for the visible rows, but I don't know how to do it differently.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Solved the Problem with the help of a friend:

```
private void ButtonClick() {
    /** get all values of the EditText-Fields */
    View v;
    ArrayList<String> mannschaftsnamen = new ArrayList<String>();
    EditText et;
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.getCount(); i++) {
        v = myList.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
        et = (EditText) v.findViewById(i);
        mannschaftsnamen.add(et.getText().toString());
    }
....
}
```

Comment: I am  trying this code but the et or relevant field always returns null for me. Do you know why?

Comment: This line et = (EditText) v.findViewById(i);  throws me null, can you guess why?

Comment: do you know why et = (EditText) v.findViewById(i); throws null?

Comment: Maybe because you need to supplement it with the real name of that element in XML?

Comment: `findViewById()` is supposed to take resource ID and not the index!

Comment: here, above code is working fine. after entered editext values, am trying to get, that time getting empty values only from EditText..

Answer (score 36):

When you use `myList.getAdapter().getView(i,null,null)` you are getting a new instance of the item view, try the `ListView.getChildAt(position)` method like this:

```
private void ButtonClick() {
    /** get all values of the EditText-Fields */
    View v;
    ArrayList<String> mannschaftsnamen = new ArrayList<String>();
    EditText et;
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.getCount(); i++) {
        v = myList.getChildAt(i);
        et = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        mannschaftsnamen.add(et.getText().toString());
    }
....
}
```

Comment: But adapter size can be different from the listview size.

Comment: `myList.getCount()` or `myList.getChildCount()`? The latter looks like more consistent

Answer (score 7):

I think the answer from @Arius was quite close to be right solution. I just want to highlight that `View` you should get is `View` which contain with `ListView`. So you need to `getChildAt(position)` related with your `ListView`.

```
private void ButtonClick() {
/** get all values of the EditText-Fields
find your ListView local variable you had created for example :
private ListView listview; 
You also need to catch null value of EditText first. */
ArrayList<String> mannschaftsnamen = new ArrayList<String>();
EditText et;
    for (int i = 0; i < listview.getCount(); i++) {
        et = (EditText) listview.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        if (et!=null) {
           mannschaftsnamen.add(String.valueOf(et.getText()));

           /** you can try to log your values EditText */
           log.v("ypgs", String.valueOf(et.getText()));
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding why the selected answer might sometimes throw a null on the "et = (EditText) v.findViewById(i);"

Would it not be at that point trying to select the item at position i WITHIN the view that you had previously selected? Thus if there are fewer items in the child views than there are items in the whole list, you would get null due to i trying to select items that don't exist.

Perhaps a nested loop could solve this problem? Or if you already know the index of the element you need, simply give it the index directly.