# How to calculate the "sum" of the values from textviews on ListItems

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I'm trying to get the values from the `TextViews` in the `Listitems`, to "sum" and calculate the total `(val1+val2+...+valn=total)`.

The structure: `ListView > listItem/RelativeLayout > TextView.`
The values come from a Custom Adapter.

*I know I need to use a iterator to count the `listItem`, and obtain the values, but i don't know how to call the rows of `listview`.

Comment: Why don't you get values from custom adapter?

Comment: I'm going to try it, thanks.

Comment: ... which is faster than converting from strings to numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the textViews on the ListView are recycled, which means most/all of them are just what the user sees, you can't use them.

The best way to do it is to perform the calculations on the data that's being used instead.

Comment: Yes, and since I think you are new to ListView, I strongly suggest you to watch "the world of ListView" (it's old, but still very useful), and maybe even watch the new RecyclerView lectures, which, according to Google, aims to replace ListView (they called it "ListView 2") .

Comment: You're right I'm new with the use of "ListView". Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ugly, but it works...

```
private int sumMyIntValues(ListView myList) {
    int sum=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.getCount(); i++) {
        View v = myList.getChildAt(i);
        TextView myView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.myView);
        sum = sum + Integer.parseInt( myView.getText().toString() )
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, finally I do it inside the adapter

Answer (score 0):

You can access the rows of a list view by calling the adapter and queuing each index.
Assuming "myList" is your list:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.getCount(); i++){
    View v = myList.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
    TextView txt = v.findViewById(  *idOfYourTextView*   );
    //Do something with the text

}
```

Referenced from: [Iterate through ListView and get EditText-Field values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293740/iterate-through-listview-and-get-edittext-field-values)