# Android getting value empty from custom list view Edittext

Tags: android, view, android-edittext, getview, listview-adapter

Am getting value here for Checkbox, and textview properly. But, I could not get the EditText Values. am getting empty only.

my sample code:

```
View view = null ;
for(int i = 0; i < list.getCount(); i++ ) {
    view = list.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null) ;

    TextView textViewNickName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview);

    String textviewValue = textViewNickName.getText().toString().trim() ;

    Log.v("ppi", "textViewNickName::"+textviewValue);

    EditText edittext = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edittext_amount)    ;

    String edittextValue = edittext.getText().toString().trim() ;

    Log.v("ppi", "Amount edittextValue::"+edittextValue);

    CheckBox checkBoxOne = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1) ;

    Log.v("ppi", "checkBoxOne::"+checkBoxOne.isChecked());

}
```

I referred this link also :
[Iterate through ListView and get EditText-Field values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293740/iterate-through-listview-and-get-edittext-field-values)

Thanks Advance

Comment: check R.id.textview have any text or empty?

Comment: textView having value.bcoz, we are passing values to textview..

Comment: only edittext dynamically entering values and trying to get it

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake to get value from `EditText`, any event time you can get value initialization time you can't get text from `EditText`

```
  EditText edittext = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edittext_amount) ;
  String edittextValue = edittext.getText().toString().trim() ;
  Log.v("ppi", "Amount edittextValue::"+edittextValue);
```

see above code that in your mistake if you have no enter any string in `EditText` then how can you retrieve initialization time.

you have to make change in you code as like blow.

```
   EditText edittext = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edittext_amount) ;

   btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String edittextValue = edittext.getText().toString().trim() ;
           Log.v("ppi", "Amount edittextValue::"+edittextValue);
        }
    });
```

Comment: thank you.. we are entering dynamic value to edittext while viewing listview. after that only, we are trying to get value from submit onclicklistener